# Finding Compatible Gem Versions for Legacy Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, legacy

I'm currently maintaining a legacy rails app version `3.0.7` and `ruby 1.8.7`. What's the best way to find what version of a specific gem is compatible with these ruby/rails versions?

Specific use-case: I've been tasked with integrating the Mailchimp API, and I'm not sure what version of `mailchimp-api` or `gibbon` to use

Comment: There is no magic method. Hopefully each project will have defined its dependency versions carefully, but this is not always the case. The latest version of `gibbon`, for example, does specify a dependency of `ruby >= 2.0.0`; but before that, no version was specified. (So did it work on `1.9.x`, or `1.8.x`? No way of knowing. Try it, and see)

Comment: [This commit](https://github.com/amro/gibbon/commit/793c6994410dd082038df8dddd827919e8313d70) added the `v2.0` constraint. Judging by that, I'd suggest using Gibbon `v1.x`. You may find that later versions also work fine, but there's no guarantee.

Comment: Of course, there's always the dreaded alternative suggestion which always comes to mind when questions like this pop up... *Why not push harder to upgrade the ruby/rails versions*? Depending on how much time you'll spend maintaining this, it may end up being more time-efficient to just upgrade/rewrite the whole thing.

Comment: Thanks @TomLord.. It does seem like an inefficient way of figuring it out, I was hoping there would be some sort of repository where I could put the dependencies I'm constrained by.

Comment: I would push for the upgrade, but the project I'm working on is going to soon be split up into microservices, which is going to take some time, but it's not worth the work of upgrading the current version for the time being

Comment: There *is* a place where you can put your dependencies: The `Gemfile`. If you write `ruby '1.8.7'`, then you'll be constrained by the ruby version. However, as I said, not all gems specify a minimum ruby version like this!

Comment: Ah! So if I specify ruby version in my Gemfile, all of the other gems without a version specified are installed according to my ruby version constraint? @TomLord

Comment: Yes. But as I've said twice, this isn't super reliable - especially for very old ruby versions. (Because many library authors never specified the ruby version constraint.)